# Laptop in a WLAN not pinging to any wired interface and vice versa

Tags: packet-tracer

I have this scenario where the laptop must be able to ping every interface and vice versa and I am not able to understand how to make the Laptop ping the router and other interfaces ?

The PCs can ping the printer and other interfaces except the laptop, only the laptop cannot ping any interface.

I have added the Wireless routers internet address as the VLANs management 1st IP address from switches.

Spent quite some hours but still not able to figure out why, when I use the simulation mode to ping PCs to wireless router the packets fail at the Inter-VLAN router and from Laptop the packets return back to wireless Laptop without going further to the wired router and without any error, I have gone through each interface and the IPs still not able to figure out whats wrong.

Any ideas ?

Packet Tracer file: http://www114.zippyshare.com/v/zF9FR3FV/file.html ALL DEVICE PASSWORDS ARE "cisco"

[image]

Thank You

Comment: If the laptop is Windows, make sure the firewall is turned off.  Also, have you verified the default gateway of the laptop?

Comment: Its not a real windows, all is in Packet Tracer simulation..

Comment: Does the wireless router have a route to the other networks and vice versa?

Comment: Its inter-VLAN routing, there is no need for routing on the router as far as I know, if you are asking about sub-interface, all sub-interfaces are created on router and switches to pass traffic, as PC can ping printer, both of which are on different networks..

Comment: Sorry I mis-read, NO the wireless router has no routing options in Packet Tracer..

Comment: Your diagram shows IP addresses on the wireless router.  Are both interfaces on the same network? In other words, is it just a bridge?

Comment: The wireless router's internet IP address is a different network, while the laptop received its IP from from the wireless routers DHCP, the wired router has subinterface of the wireless routers 1st IP, I tested again, now the issue is that the wireless router can ping all devices in the network, BUT the laptop cannot ping and return back without any error or delivering the ping either, which is strange ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packet tracer does NOT allow for Wireless routers to respond to ICMP (ping) packets, I tested this by adding a wired device to the wireless router and pinging all interfaces and it pings.

There is setting in Access Restriction in GUI tab in wireless routers which HAS to be accessed through the connected wireless PC via web browser (192.68.0.1), just enabling it will allow for the wireless PC to ping all other interfaces but NO setting for wireless router to respond to incoming ping packets.

This issue is resolved.

Thank You everyone.

Comment: You should accept your own answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

After taking a look at the attached Packet Tracer file in the original post, I've noticed that a couple of things are configured incorrectly. I've addressed the issues that affect the connectivity of the wireless laptop to the other hosts in the network.

- The Cisco 2811 router (KucRTR) has a subinterface f0/1.199 with IP
  address 10.11.4.209/29. This happens to be the same IP address as the
  WAN interface of the wireless router.
- The default gateway and the internet IP address of the internet
  connection of the wireless router are the same. Both are configured
  as 10.11.4.209/29.
- The interface f0/1 of the Cisco Catalyst 2960 switch (KucMgmt) is
  configured with VLAN 19 while the subinterface f0/1.199 of the Cisco
  2811 router is configured with VLAN ID 199.

In order for the wireless laptop to contact the other hosts in the network and vice versa, consider the following changes:

1. Change the IP address of the WAN interface of the wireless router to
   10.11.4.210/29.
2. Change the VLAN of interface f0/1 of the layer 2 switch (KucMgmt) to
   VLAN 199.